# window.onbeforeunload not working with chrome extension popup / or storage api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a google extension, and I want to store an array into the local storage of google chrome, but I don't think my window.onbeforeunload is working. When I close the extension, it it doesn't run event.

```
chrome.storage.local.get({prods: []}, function(result) {
        prods = result.prods;
        console.log(result.prods);
    })

const products = [{ name: "bag", price: 22}]
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({prods:products}, () => {
    console.log(products);
    })
}
```

reload page, and run it again the get would not be updated to the new array for some reason. (I don't think the onbeforeunload event is activating)

My manifest.json has the storage permissions already:

"permissions": [
"tabs",
"storage"
]

Any help would be great!

I've tried the function without the window.onbeforeunload, and it works fine I believe.

Comment: Are you trying to detect when the user leaves the page they are currently browsing, or when your extension popup gets closed?

Comment: onbeforeunload doesn't work in the action popup, intentionally, so you'll have to save the values immediately on change.

Comment: @CBroe When the extension popup gets closed.
wOxxOm oh i see. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to call it everytime